# Magento 1.9.x root folder - cron.sh & cron.php scripts

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a question can somebody tell me what exactly is the purpose of the Magento scripts which are located in the root directory of Magento "cron.php" & "cron.sh"

can somebody check this code

> cron.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Magento
#
# NOTICE OF LICENSE
#
# This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
# that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
# It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
# http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
# If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
# obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
# to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
#
# DISCLAIMER
#
# Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
# versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
# needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
#
# @category    Mage
# @package     Mage
# @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2018 Magento, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
# @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
#

# location of the php binary
if [ ! "$1" = "" ] ; then
    CRONSCRIPT=$1
else
    CRONSCRIPT=cron.php
fi

MODE=""
if [ ! "$2" = "" ] ; then
        MODE=" $2"
fi

PHP_BIN=`which php`

# absolute path to magento installation
INSTALLDIR=`echo $0 | sed 's/cron\.sh//g'`

#       prepend the intallation path if not given an absolute path
if [ "$INSTALLDIR" != "" -a "`expr index $CRONSCRIPT /`" != "1" ];then
    if ! ps auxwww | grep "$INSTALLDIR$CRONSCRIPT$MODE" | grep -v grep 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
        $PHP_BIN $INSTALLDIR$CRONSCRIPT$MODE &
    fi
else
    if  ! ps auxwww | grep "$CRONSCRIPT$MODE" | grep -v grep | grep -v cron.sh 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null ; then
        $PHP_BIN $CRONSCRIPT$MODE &
    fi
fi
```

and

> cron.php

```php
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2018 Magento, Inc. (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

// Change current directory to the directory of current script
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));

require 'app/bootstrap.php';
require 'app/Mage.php';

if (!Mage::isInstalled()) {
    echo "Application is not installed yet, please complete install wizard first.";
    exit;
}

// Only for urls
// Don't remove this
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);

Mage::app('admin')->setUseSessionInUrl(false);

umask(0);

$disabledFuncs = array_map('trim', explode(',', strtolower(ini_get('disable_functions'))));
$isShellDisabled = is_array($disabledFuncs) ? in_array('shell_exec', $disabledFuncs) : true;
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;

try {
    if (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) {
        $options = getopt('m::');
        if (isset($options['m'])) {
            if ($options['m'] == 'always') {
                $cronMode = 'always';
            } elseif ($options['m'] == 'default') {
                $cronMode = 'default';
            } else {
                Mage::throwException('Unrecognized cron mode was defined');
            }
        } else if (!$isShellDisabled) {
            $fileName = escapeshellarg(basename(__FILE__));
            $cronPath = escapeshellarg(dirname(__FILE__) . '/cron.sh');

            shell_exec(escapeshellcmd("/bin/sh $cronPath $fileName -mdefault 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &"));
            shell_exec(escapeshellcmd("/bin/sh $cronPath $fileName -malways 1 > /dev/null 2>&1 &"));
            exit;
        }
    }

    Mage::getConfig()->init()->loadEventObservers('crontab');
    Mage::app()->addEventArea('crontab');
    if ($isShellDisabled) {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('always');
        Mage::dispatchEvent('default');
    } else {
        Mage::dispatchEvent($cronMode);
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::printException($e);
    exit(1);
}
```

and in my crontab currently there is this execution :

```
* * * * * date >> /srv/web/public_html/var/log/cron.log;/usr/bin/php -f /srv/web/public_html/cron.php >> /srv/web/public_html/var/log/cron.log;
```

is this crontab execution properly setup?

does `/usr/bin/php -f /srv/web/public_html/cron.php` execute also `cron.sh`?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

They are for the magento cron process. Its built in cron task scheduler.

Either configure to run cron.php or cron.sh on schedule

The idea behind cron.sh is that it executes cron.php. You are meant to protect web visitors from executing cron.php via browser.

The syntax will differ between hosts. If in doubt contact your host.